# How to read from Datastore using an Ancestor query and latest golang libraries

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, deprecated, ancestor

I want to read all entities from a Datastore kind (around 6 entities/records).

I have a Datastore that is key'ed on a weird type that I am trying to understand. I can't find any uniqueness on the a key to perform a query on.
`The table looks like this:`
[GCP Datastore representing data I want to read into my Go app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RuV7C.png)

`When I click on a record, it looks like this:`
[Key literal exposed and used from here on out to try and get the records in the Go app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qoRt3.png)

``I can perform an ancestor query in the console like this:```
[GCP Datastore queried using Ancestor query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfkpK.png)

Great! So now I want to retrieve this data from my Golang App? But how?
I see a lot of solutions online about using `q.Get(...)  // where q is a *Query struct`
Any of these solutions won't work because they import `google.golang.org/appengine/datastore`. I understand that this is legacy and deprecated. So I want a solution that imports `cloud.google.com/go/datastore`.

I tried something along these lines but didn't get much luck:
[First try using GetAll and query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kPHR.png)

I tried this next:
[Second try attempting to use ancestor query... not ready yet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Izxoz.png)

Lastly I tried to get a single record directly:
[Lastly I tried to get the record directly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39oMC.png)

In all cases, my `err` is not nil and the `dts` that should be populated from datastore query is also nil.

Any guidance to help me understand how to query on this key type? Am I missing something fundamental with the way this table is key'ed and queried?

Thank you

Then I tried this:

Comment: Please edit your post, include the codes instead of picture.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are just missing your Namespace

```golang
// Merchant Struct
type MerchantDetails struct {
    MEID  string
    LinkTo *datastore.Key
    Title string
}

// Struct array to store in
var tokens []MerchantDetails

// Ancestor Key to filter by
parentKey := datastore.NameKey("A1_1113", "activate", nil)
parentKey.Namespace = "Devs1"

// The call using the new datastore UI. Basically query.Run(), but datastore.GetAll()
keys, err := helpers.DatastoreClient.GetAll(
    helpers.Ctx,
    datastore.NewQuery("A1_1112").Ancestor(parentKey).Namespace("Devs1"),
    &tokens,
)
if err != nil {
 return "", err
}

// Print all name/id from the found values
fmt.Printf("keys: %v", keys)
```